# Update a value in navbar without reloading the whole page Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, components

How do I change the value in navbar whenever there is a change in value in page component without reloading the whole page?

I get a certain value from a component and I'm saving it in the local storage.

page.component.ts

```
  getValue() {
    this.http.get(url)
        .subscribe(response => {
          this.value = response.value;
          localStorage.setItem('value', this.value);
        }
      );
    }
```

And I'm getting the value in navbar component that is saved in local storage like this: 
navbar.component.ts

```
  export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) {

      this.value =  localStorage.getItem('value');
        console.log(this.value);

      }
 }
```

The console log of the value in navbar does not change even when the value changes. It is changing only when the whole page is reloaded.

Answer (score 2):

Yer, several options

1.-Subscribe in all the component to getValue()

```
//You has a service
@Injectable()

export class myService {
   url="....."
   constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient){}
   getValue() {
      return this.httpClient.get(url);
   }
}

//In each component you need subscribe to getValue
//component1
  constructor(private myService:MyService){}
  ngOnInit()
  {
        myService.getValue().subscribe(res=>
             {
                ..do something..
             }
   }
```

2.-If your components have a parent-child relation, subscribe in the parent and pass the value to children

```
//parent
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <app-children [data]="data">
  `
  })
  data:any
  constructor(private myService:MyService){}

  ngOnInit()
  {
        myService.getValue().subscribe(res=>
             {
                this.data=res
             }
   }

//children
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    {{data}}
  `
  })

 @Input()data
```

3.-Store the value in the service and use a getter when you need

```
//Your service store the variable
@Injectable()

    export class myService {
       url="....."
       data:any //<--we store the data in this variable
       constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient){}
       getValue() {
          //Use "tap" to do something with the response
          return this.httpClient.get(url).pipe(tap(res=>
             {
                this.data=res
             }));
       }
    }

//In your component you use
  constructor(private myService:MyService){}
  get data()
  {
       return this.myService.data;
  }
  ngOnInit()
  {
      //You must subscribe in one and only one component, not need subscribe
      //Really you can do it in the own service
        myService.getValue().subscribe()
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with using the local storage is that the `NavbarComponent` will read whatever is stored in the local storage before it is updated by the HTTP request.

I recommend looking into Observables & HTTP: https://angular.io/guide/http

Your `getValue()` function should return an Observable that the `NavbarComponent` can subscribe to and update a local variable once the HTTP response comes back.

For example, in the page.component.ts, return the following:

```
getValue() {
    return this.http.get(url);
}
```

Then in the navbar.component.ts, subscribe to the observable that `getValue()` returns:

```
constructor(private page: PageComponent) {
    this.page.getValue().subscribe(response => {
        this.value = response.value;
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you show any example of how to use observables?